# Actionscript 3 error: definition DNSResolver could not be found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am using adobe flash cc 2015 to writing actionscript3 flash and I am trying to use DNSResolver.

the relevant code like this:

```
import DNSResolver;
var resolver:DNSResolver = new DNSResolver();
resolver.addEventListener(DNSResolverEvent.LOOKUP,lookupComplete);
     resolver.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR,lookupError);
     resolver.lookup(url,ARecord);
     resolver.lookup(url,AAAARecord);
     resolver.lookup(url,MXRecord);
     function lookupComplete(){
         trace("hahahahaha\n");
     }
     function lookupError(){
         trace("ffffffffaaaaa\n");
     }
```

and I have try lots of import method such as

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.DNSResolverEvent;
import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.dns.AAAARecord;
import flash.net.dns.ARecord;
import flash.net.dns.DNSResolver;
import flash.net.dns.MXRecord;
import flash.net.dns.PTRRecord;
import flash.net.dns.SRVRecord;
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;
```

or
    import flash.net.dns;

but the same error came up all the time:
1120: Access of undefined property MXRecord.
1120: Access of undefined property AAAARecord.
1120: Access of undefined property ARecord.
1120: Access of undefined property DNSResolverEvent.
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method DNSResolver.
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: DNSResolver.
1172: Definition DNSResolver could not be found.
1172: Definition DNSResolver could not be found.

anyone know how to solve this problem?
am I import the wrong packages or there are some points I missed?
Thanks!

Comment: `DNSResolver` is in the `flash.net.dns` package, so `import flash.net.dns.*` Remember the resolver features are only available on Air Desktop profiles so use the `isSupported` to check...

Comment: Those classes are exclusively AIR so you can only use them in a AIR app. Using "isSupported" would not solve anything since the classes themselves cannot be used if the app is not AIR based.